# GrammaTech CodeSonar - output to CSV

Tags: static-analysis

I need to export **GrammaTech CodeSonar**'s analysis from my browser's hub to a CSV.

However, I want to include my Notes, but don't know how to include them in the export.

Please tell me how to export my Notes, along with the other rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the Notes field in your CSV, you need to show it in the table before clicking the CSV link.  To do this, click on any column header on the table of warnings and then select 'Show Notes' from the menu that appears (it will be the last option on the menu).

Once the notes are displayed in the table, they will also be included in the CSV.

Comment: thanks. It's great to know that GrammaTech scrolls forums to help out its users!